# LC power filter, big L or big C?

Tags: power, capacitor, filter, inductor, passive-networks

I was reading a datasheet for a Murata DC-DC converter [Murata DC-DC converter](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807031177246/kdc-nmg.pdf?1583754812000). It has the following LC filter recommendation to reduce output ripple:
[image]

As the output voltage of the DC-DC converter goes up, the recommended L value goes goes up and the C value goes down so that the cutoff frequency stays roughly the same at 20kHz.

Why would C be traded for L as the voltage output increases as opposed to keeping the L and C values the same for all voltage outputs (since they all provide the same cutoff frequency)?

Comment: This [AN](https://www.ti.com/lit/an/snva871/snva871.pdf?ts=1599420606544) from TI explores the subject of adding an output \$LC\$ filter to an existing converter. Keep in mind that doing so affects the output impedance and the filter shall be selected so that transient response is not degraded. Also, unlike certain recommendations below, keep the inductance low to minimize its insertion loss and degrade the dc error at full load.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the different output voltage versions of this converter series have the same power, therefore output voltage is inversely proportional to current.

Ceramic capacitors of a given value become more expensive at higher voltage, but inductors of a given value become less expensive at lower current. So it makes sense to decrease C and increase L with increasing voltage.

Higher inductance increases converter output impedance, but the higher voltage versions have lower output current, which compensates this.

Also, capacitance at the output is mostly what existing decoupling caps you'll have on your load, plus one cap right at the output of the LC filter to provide a short low inductance path to ground for HF noise. And higher current load tends to imply higher decoupling capacitance.

So the datasheet tells you, since you probably have that much decoupling capacitance on your load already, you can pick this inductor value.

Answer (score 2):

With increasing output voltage the specified output current is decreasing:

[image]

With lower output current the inductor ripple current needs to be lower as well thus requiring a higher inductance.

Although this component seems to be using an isolating topology, it might still be worth to take a look at this [LC Selection guide](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/AND9135-D.PDF).

Comment: The document seems to be targeted at selecting boost converter L and C values. The LC filter in the Murata datasheet is just for ripple reduction (it already has a transformer inside). Or do the same principles apply?

Answer (score 2):

There is also a dimension of Cost.

Data sheet says that the capacitor that you are talking about should be of ceramic types (it says it is recommended, but it is good to use what they recommend unless you know why you are doing!) and it's voltage rating should be double the value of the DC-DC output Voltage. So lets say we want output of 24V, so we need a ceramic capacitor of 1uF (as specified in data sheet) rated 48V. Now that capacitor from the same company cost about $0.58 on Digikey! Although, less expansive caps are available from other companies. Now, as you said that you want to increase the the capacitance rather than increasing the inductance, so lets say you need 10uF 50V ceramic caps, then again same company price it at $2.71!! And you know why they are expansive? Because high voltage high capacitance ceramic capacitor are always expansive.

Increasing the inductor values is easy, just put more turns on the coil! So it is an inexpensive options to increase the value of inductor than increase the value of capacitor.